# Install any drivers, 3rd party app on single click

Tags: c#, installation

I have one hardware device which has signature pad and biometric reader in it.
and I need to prepare the installation guide document for the same with corresponding driver files.

Since the installation of this hardware is huge(~more than 300 devices need to  instal on customer site). I would like to create a app which will do the installation (Automatically clicking next button , finish button etc). for both signature pad and biometric reader driver installation.

note: User will not going to change any installation path, or etc .

How can i acheive this using C#.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Go through this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automatically-install-required-software-after-a-reinstall/)

May be it gives what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the same, yes it gave me some ideas.